# Redirect from subfolder to new domain?

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, iis-7, url-rewrite-module

I have no idea about ASP.NET. I have recently started learning PHP. But I faced a problem with IIS hosting. Actually in it is not a problem, it is something I want to do. I checked here and google different rules applied them but it did work for me. So here I am asking your help guys.

Could you please write me a rule for my web.config.

I need 301 redirects from subfolder to the new domain.

Here how it looks like

```
domain.com/folder/* ----> newdomain.com
```

Thank you in advance!

I have tried different rules, tried to adapt it to my need but didn't succeed.

Comment: You should try to convert .htaccess to web.config file.
Read this link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig

Answer (score 3):

The following rule implements the redirect you are describing.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Test" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="folder/(.*)" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain.com$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://newdomain.com" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

- The `<match url="folder/(.*)" />` part will check the URL and will match all requests that begin with `folder/`.
- The `<add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain.com$" />` will match the top-level domain
- The `<action type="Redirect" url="http://newdomain.com" />` specifies where the request will redirected
- The `redirectType="Permanent"` will set the status code of the redirect to be 301.